# Php - Redirection Failed after writing contents in language file containing php Constants

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

I have language related Constants defined in a php file, that can be edited from admin side, After editing the contents, any page that include it, failed to successfully redirect using php header function.

As error reporting is off, it don't generate warning message and same page refreshed after form submission instead of redirecting to another page.

Any help.

Comment: paste some code & on error_reporting to know where output already sent

Answer (score 1):

There is probably some output already being sent to the users browser when you're setting the redirect header.

Setting HTTP headers after sending content won't work. You'll have to suppress any output until you sent the header.

Comment: Yes, you are right, after editing the language file in contain some illegal chars or white spaces, as file included before the  php code block that redirect to a second page.  But i want to know, what cause this output, as if i don't change any thing in file and press save button it cause redirection issue.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is correct. check whether headers are already flushed with `header_sent`

For debugging you can see where the mistake is:

```
<?php
if( headers_sent( $in_file, $at_line ) ){
    trigger_error('Cannot write redirect header, output started at '.$at_line.' in '.$in_file, E_USER_ERROR );
}
```

Likely mistakes causing early output are:

- Accidental text entered before `<?php` at beginning of files.
- Accidental text after `?>` at end of files. (not needed and should be omitted anyway)
- Error output. (especially notices raised - likely if using Wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

use following function to resolve this  problem:

```
ob_start();
```

Comment: before file inclusion, do you think it will not anticipate any issue in currently developed solution. Is there need for flush?

Comment: will prevent output, but will disguise actual cause of problem. Also not a full answer, because you'll have to call ob_end_clean() later on

Comment: @Tim yes, i was thinking same, is there any overhead of using ob_start().

Comment: @vijay ,  I write ob_start() in include file and ob_end_clean() at the end of include file, and it don't worked, BUT if i use only ob_start() at the start only , then it works. Can you tell, where i can start and end Output buffering.

Comment: @Asad..Basically you don't need to include  ob_end_clean() . Script will redirect automatically when it get header-location function. According to convention we can't generate any html output before header function.But due to any circumstance if any output is generating so we just cheat to system by ob_start function that no output is generating because output is in buffer.

Answer (score 0):

replace the header with javascript redirection

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="membre.php";</script>';
```

Comment: Language file is included in all site pages, i have to change all headers in all pages with java-script. And if a browser donot support then my script will again fail.

Answer (score 0):

Are your files' encoding "UTF-8"? May be, your text editor added BOM-record in UTF-8 file. And it crashed PHP header function. If you  use UTF-8 encoding, you should save file as "UTF-8 without BOM"

Comment: I created a new file and copy the text from original file(i carefully check in Dreamweaver BOM mark was unchecked). Uploaded to server: No Issue, redirection Ok. But as i just on admin side editing page same contents loaded in textarea and i pressed save button without changing any thing. ISSUE, redirection failed.